# How many unique composites can be produced by multiplying together n primes from a list of m primes?

Tags: probability, prime-numbers, combinations

I heard that Euclid proved that there are infinitely many primes and decided to take a crack at it before contaminating my brain with the solution. Needless to say, Euclid's was much more elegant than mine, but in order to complete my proof, I need a formula which describes the number of unique composite numbers that will be generated by multiplying n primes together, where there are m primes to choose from. So if n is 3, and m is 2, and my primes are a and b, then we have 4 composites that can be created:

aaa
aab
abb
bbb

I have always had a hard time with probability, and I'm stumped on how to generalize this. What I am trying to show is that if you suppose there is a greatest prime number, that means that all numbers greater than that prime must be composites. Therefore, for any arbitrary interval from P to P^n, where P is the largest prime number, the unique combinations of n primes (ie the total number of composites) must be greater than or equal to P^n-P (where P^n is the largest composite that can be made by multiplying n primes together) for any n. Otherwise, the set of numbers in that interval would be larger than the possible number of combinations of n primes, and thus there would not be enough composite numbers to cover every number in the set. If there aren't enough composites, then some of the numbers must be prime. That may be poorly expressed, but what I really need is the formula describing the possible number of composites that can be created by multiplying together n primes chosen from a list of m available primes. Anyone care to help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is
$$ n+m-1\choose m-1$$
by a [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) argument. Good luck in completing this to a proof!

Comment: I was able to complete my proof, although I did not end up needing this particular method. Thanks for the help. [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2260137/441690) is the proof if you are interested.